# WiFi no longer working

Tags: wireless, networking, indicator

My network indicator was not showing up in in my menu bar. I saw someone else had a similar question, so I tried running the same things that they did. I ran `apt-get install indicator-network` and also `apt-get install network-manager-gnome`.

The networks still show up in my network settings, I am just unable to connect to them.

Results of `rfkill list`:

> ```
> isaac@isaac-ThinkPad-T440s:~$ rfkill list
> 0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
>         Soft blocked: yes
>         Hard blocked: no
> 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
>         Soft blocked: yes
>         Hard blocked: no
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only soft blocked, you can run `sudo rfkill unblock all`

If it were hard blocked, then you would need to change a physical switch on the laptop.